How to trigger/skip Airflow dag execution based files from SFTP server
Can you suggest a solution on how to trigger or skip airflow dag execution based on file availability from SFTP server ?
Scenario:
We will receive file in sftp server , we can schedule a dag for every 5mins or 10mins to check sftp server path. In case file available it should continue and execute next tasks (such as download file and load file etc).
In case file doesn't exists in SFTP path airflow should skip execution of next tasks.
Solution Tried:

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.sftp.sensors.sftp import SFTPSensor
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
from future.core.common_tasks import dag_start, dag_end
import pendulum
import os
import pendulum
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable



dag_id = os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".pyc", "").replace(".py", "")

with DAG(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    schedule = "*/5 * * * *",
    is_paused_upon_creation=True,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    max_active_runs= 1,
    catchup=False
):


    wait_for_new_file= SFTPSensor(task_id="wait_for_new_file",                        
                        path=fullpath,
                        file_pattern='*.txt',
                        sftp_conn_id="sftp_conn",                        
                        #deferrable=True,                    
                        newer_than=None)
    
    get_file = BashOperator(
                            task_id='get_sql_tracedata',
                            
                        )
    load_file = BashOperator(
                             task_id='loadfile',
                            
                        )
    
    wait_for_new_file >> get_file >> load_file

Problem:
SFTP sensor task kept connecting to sftp even the file doesn't exists.

Your actual use case is unclear. Do you expect 1 file for each interval a DAG is supposed to run ?
If your DAG is running every 10 minutes, what you want to do might not a sensor, it might be branch condition.

@vdolez To put it simple. We receive files (not with regular intervals , it can be couple of times on some days or no files at all for couple of days) in sftp server and when it arrives we need to get files and do some processing with it.

Does your SFTP server support outgoing webhooks? If it does, you could configure one to trigger the airflow dag via the ReST API.
